# Income At the Sell or Reception?

Tags: united-states, taxes, cryptocurrency, virtual-currency

[See this from the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/uac/newsroom/irs-virtual-currency-guidance):

> The character of gain or loss from the sale or exchange of virtual currency depends on whether the virtual currency is a capital asset in the hands of the taxpayer.

Scenario A: John mines 2 Monero in 2017 at a price point of ($20 x 1) and ($23 x 1), but doesn't sell.  Is this $43 in income, or is it income *only when* he sells?

Scenario B: Jane mines 0.1 Bitcoin in five different chunks of 0.02 each at a price in each chunk of ($1400 x 0.02), ($1401 x 0.02), ($1405 x 0.02), ($1407 x 0.02) and ($1408 x 0.02).  She sells her 0.1 Bitcoin at a *Bitcoin price point* of $3000 per Bitcoin, meaning she *made* $300.  Based on the IRS site, what does she owe in taxes?

Per the first question below: so, Jane owes taxes on the income of 140.42 (28 + 28.02 + 28.1 + 28.14 + 28.16)?  Now, she then sells that 0.1 Bitcoin for $300.  Is the cost basis for the sell $140.42, so a *capital gain* of 159.58?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like fair-market value when you receive your virtual currency is counted as income. And you're also subject to self-employment tax on that income. Here's an [FAQ from the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-drop/n-14-21.pdf):

> **Q-8: Does a taxpayer who “mines” virtual currency (for example, uses
>   computer resources to validate Bitcoin transactions and maintain the
>   public Bitcoin transaction ledger) realize gross income upon receipt
>   of the virtual currency resulting from those activities?** 
> A-8: Yes,
>   when a taxpayer successfully “mines” virtual currency, the fair market
>   value of the virtual currency as of the date of receipt is includible
>   in gross income. See Publication 525, Taxable and Nontaxable Income,
>   for more information on taxable income.
> **Q-9: Is an individual who
>   “mines” virtual currency as a trade or business subject to
>   self-employment tax on the income derived from those activities?** 
> A-9:
>   If a taxpayer’s “mining” of virtual currency constitutes a trade or
>   business, and the “mining” activity is not undertaken by the taxpayer
>   as an employee, the net earnings from self-employment (generally,
>   gross income derived from carrying on a trade or business less
>   allowable deductions) resulting from those activities constitute
>   selfemployment income and are subject to the self-employment tax. See
>   Chapter 10 of Publication 334, Tax Guide for Small Business, for more
>   information on selfemployment tax and Publication 535, Business
>   Expenses, for more information on determining whether expenses are
>   from a business activity carried on to make a profit.

You'd of course be able to offset that income with the expense of mining the virtual currency, depreciation of dedicated mining equipment, electricity, not sure what else.

Edit: Here's a good resource on [filing taxes with Bitcoin](http://Filing%20your%20Bitcoin%20Taxes%20-%20Losses,%20Income%20&%20Spending):

> **Filling in the 1040**
>  Income from Bitcoins and all crypto-currencies is
>   declared as either capital gains income or ordinary income, for
>   example from mining. 
> **Income**
>  Ordinary income will be declared on either
>   your 1040 (line 21 - Other Income) for an individual, or within your
>   Schedule C, if you are self-employed or have sole-proprietor business.
>   
> **Capital Gains**
>  Capital gains income, or losses, are declared on
>   Schedule D. Since there are no reported 1099 forms from Bitcoin
>   exchanges, you will need to include your totals with Box C checked for
>   short-term gains, and with Box F checked for long-term gains.

Interesting notes from that article, your first example could actually be trickier than expected if you started mining before there was a Monero to USD exchange. Also, there can also be capital gains implications from using your virtual currency to buy goods, which sounds like a pain to keep track of.

Comment: So, Jane owes taxes on the income of 140.42 (28 + 28.02 + 28.1 + 28.14 + 28.16)?  Now, she then sells that 0.1 Bitcoin for $300.  Is the cost basis for the sell $140.42, so a *capital gain* of 159.58?

Comment: @JugiChibor0 That's my understanding, but you'd offset the income with expenses associated with mining, and that wouldn't affect the basis for your capital gain calculation.